# How get the particular part for a string?

Tags: custom-fields, string

How to get a particular part of a string? e.g after some special characters or some words.

Comment: Bit vague on your requirement, how about an example in a template? Is the string output by channel:entries for example? Are the words you're searching for dynamic or consistent?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [PHPStringFun](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/phpstringfun) add-on and use regX either with substr or str_replace. Alternatively you could use [Low Replace](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-replace) or [MX Jumper](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-jumper). Or you could even activate PHP on the template and post parse. All depends on your exact requirement.

Comment: A simple PHP `substr()` should do, I think. But yes, would be nice to know a bit more about the OPs requirements.

Comment: Or as someone pointed out to me, you might want to use `mb_substr()` depending if you have utf8 characters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120732/difference-between-mb-sustr-and-substr